# CSS row background color visual issue

Tags: html, css, html-table, background-color

I've got a strange visual issue. If the background of a row is colorized (black), and a cell inside the row with a different background color (yellow), there's a thin diagonal stroke inside the yellow cells:

[image]

I was unable to reproduce the issue outside of the customer's website. (Chrome, 62.0.3202.75)

But the strokes disappear if i remove this line of code:

```
.ctable thead tr,
.ctable tbody tr:nth-child(even) {
    background: black;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/4fLf29o1/4/ (not-able-to-reproduce example)

How can this happen?

Comment: I believe that's a Chrome bug. Try to disable GPU rasterization in `about://flags`.

Comment: When you say you can't repro outside of the customer's website, does that mean you can't repro with your jsfiddle either? I don't see the issue in your jsfiddle. (Though I'm on a retina mac, which may contribute.)

Comment: @dgrogan Yes, exactly. The fiddle link does only show my not-able-to-reproduce example.

Comment: @Jackowski You're right, the lines do not appear with GPU rasterization = Disabled. But i can't tell every customer to disable this option.

Comment: Search crbug.com for similar issues. If there are you can try to use any suggested workarounds. If there are no similar issues then try harder to get a minimal standalone reproduction and when you do, submit a new crbug and respond here with the link to it.